# Getting data from sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am using android and sqlite database, I want to get data from colum `nomMission`
this is what I have done but it is not working

```
 public List<Missions> getMissions() {
    List<Missions> mission = new ArrayList<Missions>();

    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select nomMission from Missions", null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Missions missionss = cursorToMission(cursor);
        mission.add(missionss);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return mission;
}

private Missions cursorToMission(Cursor cursor) {
    Missions missions = new Missions(null, null);
    missions.setNomMission(cursor.getString(1));
    missions.setDateMission(cursor.getString(2));
    return missions;
}
```

Error Log:

```
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tn.pfe.ybn.sigl/tn.pfe.ybn.sigl.DataManip.MissionAct}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 16:04:52.347: E/AndroidRuntime(4864): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your cursor actually contains only a column.
Which index is **0** (table columns are 0 based).

You specify:

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select nomMission from Missions", null);
```

(one column)

But then you try to access

```
missions.setNomMission(cursor.getString(1));
missions.setDateMission(cursor.getString(2));
```

In your case, you can only access:

```
missions.setNomMission(cursor.getString(0));
```

or, better,

```
missions.setNomMission(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nomMission")));
```

Here you refer the column(s) by **name**, not by **index**

Comment: i changed it but i always have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If your query only selects one column, it will only return one column with an index of 0. The way it is now, you can call `cursor.getString(0)` and that's really it.  If you want to get NomMission and DateMission, you should call

`Cursor cursor = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT nomMission AND dateMission FROM Missions",null);

Personally, I prefer to use the SQLiteDatabase's [query method here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

For you, that would look like

`Cursor cursor = mDb.query("Missions, new String[]{"nomMission", "dateMission"},null, null, null, null, null, null);`

I'm also a noob, so anybody feel free to correct anything.